# Is there any standard way to Modify node packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules, yarnpkg

I am Trying to make one application using node(React JS) and I have requirement which is already in one node package( react-image-gallery ). But the things is that I have to make so many changes in that node package and it should be standard. by standard I mean that the version controlling should be followed.
If you have any suggestion for modify the node package then please provide me.